# Вывод оставшегося времени без re-load

Tags: php, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Я хочу сделать таймер обратного отсчета. Вот что получилось. Теперь возник вопрос, как мне сделать с помощью js , чтобы полученная дата обновлялась, без перезагрузки страницы ?

<?

$time = time();

$result = 1389277663; //unix time

$chislo = $result - $time ;

echo $s = date( "s", $chislo ) .'<br>' ; //секунды

echo $i = date( "i", $chislo ) .'<br>'; //минуты

echo $h = date( "H", $chislo ) .'<br>' ; //часы

echo $d = date( "d", $chislo ) .'<br>'; // дни

echo $m = date( "m", $chislo ) .'<br>'; // месяцы

echo $y = date( "Y", $chislo ) .'<br>' ; //годы

/*

Результат : sec min hour day month year
             34 34   07  11   09    1970

*/
? >

Answer (score 2):

Используйте методы работы со временем в JS а так же setInterval().
При загрузке страницы получаете разницу во времени ($chislo) в js переменную, и раз в секунду (с помощью setInterval) отнимаете одну секунду, перерасчитываете время, и вставляете на страницу.